# Изменить содержимое SESSION PHP

Tags: php, сессия

При авторизации пользователя на сайте - для него создаётся сессия, в которой, помимо прочего, сохраняется его логин.
В случае изменения логина пользователя администратором - пользователю необходимо пересоздать сессию (выйти и снова зайти) чтобы изменения стали ему видны.
Вопрос заключается в следующем: как, при изменении логина в базе данных сразу внести обновлённые данные в файл сессии, зная ID этой сессии?

Я понимаю что зная ID можно открыть файл сессии, перебрать его и заменив данные - снова сохранить, но может есть более правильный вариант?

Comment: Тебе именно это решение необходимо - то-есть перезаписать сессию в файле? Поскольку можно просто поставить какой-нибудь флаг для пользователя в его таблице например updateSession. Когда админ изменит логин то установит флаг true. Как пользователь обратиться к серверу то проверяется этот флаг и если он true то сессия перезаписывается с обновлёнными данными, а флаг updateSession устанавливается false.

Comment: Перезапись сессии в файл не самая лучшая идея - поскольку в PHP есть множество настроек для сессии. Например доступ к файлам сессии может быть не асинхронным и если пользователь логин которого изменён обращается к серверу то в данный момент не удастся изменить файл сессии поскольку он занят. Или сессия может храниться не в файле, а скажем в memcached-е. Или в файле сессии может храниться сессия не одного пользователя, а нескольких. Кроме того в PHP есть два алгоритма сохранения сессии и скорее всего обе будет необходимо поддерживать ( ini_get("session.serialize_handler") ).

Comment: @DanielAbyan Ваши комментарии годятся на хороший ответ!

Comment: По поводу хранения флагов - безусловно, можно. Но идея как раз в том, чтобы минимизировать количество запросов к БД. Это же нужно где-нибудь впихнуть лишний запрос к таблице пользователя, а с учётом что произойти это изменение может в любом момент - этот запрос должен быть вообще везде, а учитывая что он может понадобиться раз в пятилетку - то все эти пять лет это будет абсолютно не нужный запрос. Потому вопрос и возник. Я тут начал копать с сторону Redis, на сколько понимаю - то что мне нужно с ним будет сделать гораздо легче в сессиях. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Да кончено Redis может решить эту проблему. Сессии будут храниться в оператовной памяти - которая в свою очередь доступна из всех уголков сайта. Кроме того увеличится производительность поскольку данные будут считываться из оперативной памяти, а не из накопителя. Но это в том случае если ваш сайт действительно нуждается в этом. Если нет острой необходимости то интеграция ещё одой технологии в сайт может добавить проблем. Можешь посмотреть вот [здесь](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-redis-server-as-a-session-handler-for-php-on-ubuntu-14-04)